# Stripe paymentIntents issue

Tags: stripe-payments

I am using stripe for the payment integration.
And I am facing one issue while creating payment intent on server.
If I run my project on localhost and call the API to create a payment intent, then it works perfectly and adds a payment intent in my stripe account also.
But as soon as I deployed the project and called the API from server, I am getting the response with paymentIntent Id(client_secret), but it is not getting saved in my stripe account.
And at the time of payment, I am getting error:

> resource_missing - intent No such payment_intent:
> 'pi_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'

Please help!

Comment: A `resource_missing` is normally an indication of a mismatch in API keys (often between test and live mode). Double check that the API used to create the PaymentIntent is from the same environment (test/live) as the API key you're using to perform other actions.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! 
Yes, I checked the keys and the secret key was wrong on the server!

Comment: No problem! Happy to help.